# correlation of conditional mean function and its parts

Tags: probability, statistics

The random variables Y and X have a bivariate normal distribution with means 1 and 2, variances 2 and 5 and covariance 3. Compute the squared correlation between y and E[y|x].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** For two jointly normal variables, $X$ and $Y$, we have:
$$ \mathrm E\left[ Y|X\right] = \mathrm E\left[ Y\right]+ \frac{\mathrm{Cov}\left[X,Y\right]}{\mathrm V\left[X \right]} \left(X -\mathrm E\left[ X\right] \right) = \frac{3}{5}X-\frac{1}{5}, $$
that is, conditional expectation $\mathrm E\left[ Y|X\right]$ is a linear function of $X$.

Variances and covariance (hence correlation) of $Y$ and $\frac{3}{5}X-\frac{1}{5}$ are then easy to compute with given data.